# Can I patch 'random' using unittest.mock.patch?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I'm interested in testing some code that uses the 'random' module, and I'd like to be able to patch/insert my own fake version of random when my tests are running, that returns a known value, and put it back to the normal random module afterwards. From the documentation I can only see that I can patch classes. Is there a way to patch functions? Something like this:

```
def my_code_that_uses_random():
    return random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3])

with patch.function(random.choice, return_value=3) as mock_random:
    choice = my_code_that_uses_random()
    assert choice == 3
```

That code doesn't work, what do I need instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`patch.function` doesn't seem to exist. You can use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) itself instead:

```
with patch('random.choice', return_value=3) as mock_random:
    choice = my_code_that_uses_random()
    assert choice == 3
```

Comment: If you need to replace it with a real function you can replace `return_value` with: `side_effect=lambda seq: seq[0]`.   This will let you actually test passing in sequences and getting elements out.  In this case, it will always "choose" the first element.